# How to prevent form submit when a button clicked?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form where a button included, when button is clicked the form is submitted, and how to prevent this. for example I just want to show a "alert" when the button is clicked. and put the button outside of form is not a option for me.

and BTW I use bootstrap framework.

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" id="form-area">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="dept-area">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-area">test</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't agree with the javascript answers. They work, but they're not fixing the cause of the problem.

The form is being submitted because the `<button>` element has a type of `submit` by default (see the [spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)).

You can get around this by putting `type="button"` in the html like so:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-area">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.preventDefault();`

clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL. We can use event.isDefaultPrevented() to determine if this method has been called by an event handler that was triggered by this event.

```
 $("#btn-area").click( function(event) {


 event.preventDefault();

     alert("hello ");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BL3Jk/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#form-area').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use jquery like this

```
$("#btn-area").click(function(event){
alert("Your alert");
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Please see the updated ans